# I'm facing problems on running code in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I click on run button to run the code in Virtual Studio Code(Python), it shows two option:(Image attached below)

1. Run Code
2. Run python file in Terminal

But I want to run my code on simply clicking on run button.
I tried searching setting..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0AjU.png)

Comment: This is the intended way to do it and it's up to you to choose one, depending on your problem.

Comment: @GhostBot -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code, the green run button provided by the "Python" extension is to execute the command "`Run Python File in Terminal`". It only requires us to click once to allow python files in the Terminal of VS Code:

[image]

If you also use other extensions, such as: "Code Runner", the run button ("Run Code") provided by it defaults to output results in "OUTPUT". In the previous use, this button will overwrite the green button provided by the "python" extension, but now that they are integrated, we can choose the execution method.

Since you want to click the run button only once, you could click "[Start Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)" or F5 to debug the code or try to close the "Code Runner" extension. (Click "`Enable`" can restore the use of the extension.)

Answer (score 0):

You can press `f5` to run code with debugging and `ctrl f5` for running code without debugging. If you are specifically trying to run python, try `ctrl alt n`

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the Code Runner extension. It does all the terminal work for you so you can just run it with the click of a button.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner